# jQuery selector for link without an image inside

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I bind a `click` function to a link:

```
$("body").on("click", "a", function() {
    //do something
});
```

Now I am looking for a selector that will only match if the link does not contain an image tag. So kind of similar to `a:not(img)` but `img` being the child element.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("body").on("click", "a:not(a:has(img))", function() {
    //do whatever you want here
});
```

Comment: I'd be more specific by providing a selector prior to calling `:has`, so `:has` doesn't try to match every element in the page. `a:not(a:has(img))` should provide better performance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`not`](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) with [`has`](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) to filter anchors not having `img`

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kuWk6/3/)**

```
$("body").on("click", "a:not(a:has(img))", function() {
    //do something
    alert("");
});
```

​

Comment: You just forgot the `a` this time but +1 for the first answer including `has`.

Comment: Thanks @FabrícioMatté I could not get you forgot a?

Comment: lacking `a` before the `:not`:  `$("body").on("click", "a:not(a:has(img))"`, otherwise you would be delegating the handler to all elements which aren't links with images instead of just links which have no images: http://jsfiddle.net/kuWk6/2/. `:P`

Comment: Thanks again @FabrícioMatté, so nice of you, I realised after asking you but I was away from my machine, now read your message and corrected.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$('a:not(:has(>img))').click(function(){
    alert('click');
})​;
```