# Applying CSS to <a that has no <img child

Tags: css

I am using a special link effect on `<a>` tags with the background-image: CSS. The links look nice but the website also contains a lot of `<img>` that are links, which also get the CSS.

I am currently solving the issue with jQuery: `$("img").parent().css("background", "none");`
Is there any correct way of doing this with CSS, getting this CSS not to affect  tags.

Code:

```
a:link ,a:visited {
    text-decoration: none;
    background-image: url(/underline.png);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-position: bottom;
}
```

Comment: Please post your code. Without it this question is too ambiguous.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery selector for link without an image inside](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14004978/jquery-selector-for-link-without-an-image-inside)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I saw this: `background-image: url(/underline.png);` I got very nervous. Is there some special effect you need to employ here? What's wrong with the underline property in CSS?

To solve this in CSS2 you'll need to redesign your code. Therefore, this might be a bit impractical.

Keep your css code for links.

Then wherever you have a link with an image in there, you should add a class. Use this class to link CSS that overrides the typical behavior.

There is no way to do what you want in current CSS capabilities. Jquery works but it is afterall a hack.

```
 a {
   code here that you want
 }
 a.img {
   override properties
 }

 <!-- Html -->
 <a href="#">Normal Text</a>
 <a class="img" href="#"><img src="image.png" width="x" height="y" alt="" /></a>
```

Some food for thought -> The reason CSS does not support what you seek is because a child should not define a parent's style! AFterall, we (as people) do not define our parents' traits but we surely override what we inherited.

Answer (score 1):

CSS4 defines the following syntax:

```
!a>img {background-image:none}
```

However, as far as I'm aware no browser supports it yet. It's also not final on where the `!` goes, as `a!>img` and `!a!>img` all have been suggested.

So, basically, there is no CSS solution for this. However, there is a "hack" solution.

Assuming `body {background:white}`, you can do this:

```
a>img {background:white}
```

This will cover up the link's background with a white one, which essentially hides it. Adjust the colour as needed. Note that this won't work if your content area has a background image...

Comment: Thanks for the hack tip, but unfortunately I don't have white background behind most images.

Comment: If you have any solid colour, you can use that instead.

Answer (score 0):

What would be the difference in your links ?
Domain, peticular folders, extension name , etc...
I asked cause you could filter them by url.

```
[href~=picto] will mathch if url contains picto or something similar
[href^="image/] will match any url begining with  image/whatever_is_behind_or_not
[href*="image/] will match any url containing  image/
[href$=".jpg"] will match any url ending with this .jpg extension
```

As you can see , there's nowdays lots of option , level4 will make it much easier though :)

Comment: a:link only match <a> with "href" attributes, not anchors

Answer (score 0):

Well, unless I am missing something, the solution to this is rather simple.

On a website I worked on I used the following two CSS rules to differentiate between linked text effects and linked image effects:

```css
a:link {
  /* rules for linked text effects */
}

a img {
  /* rules for linked img effects */
}
```

Comment: This does not work because he wants to change the link styles and not the img styles.

Comment: @ProfileTwist Yeah I just re-read the question and saw how the methods for his jquery selector indeed point to the link tag.