# jQuery selector for link without html inside

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I search a solution to find all link in a text that not contains html tags.

I have a start of solution, like this :

```
jQuery("a:not(a:has(img), a:has(span), ...)").addClass('myclass');
```

Found here : [jQuery selector for link without an image inside](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14004978/jquery-selector-for-link-without-an-image-inside)

but I'll wish a thing like this :

```
jQuery("a:not(a:has(all-html-element))").addClass('myclass');
```

I don't know if find if my link has a child it's a better solution, like this :

```
if(jQuery("a").children().size() == 0)
{
//do some stuff
}
```

What do you think?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$("a").filter(function(){
    return $(this).children().length == 0;
})
```

Comment: thanks. This is another good solution. In your opinion, what is the best solution between :has(*) and yours ?

Comment: My approach will likely be faster.  As the jquery docs for `:has` state, you normally don't want to use it as part of a complex selector.

Comment: Okay, I understood. Sorry for my english, I'm little rusty. I think I'll choose your solution.

Answer (score 2):

Use the following selector:

```
$('a:not(:has(*))').addClass("myclass");
```

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/itay1989/ebrEL/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
$("a").filter(function() {
  return $(this).text() == $(this).html();
}).addClass('myclass');
```

text() will remove all html tags, if this is same as return of html(), you will have only elements without containing html tags.

Answer (score 0):

just check if the current a-element has any children:

```
$("a").filter(function(){
    return this.children.length === 0; // check if the element has any DOM elements
}).addClass("myclass");
```